# Undefined Index fileToUpload in .... on line

Tags: php, html, image-size

I have to do this for a class project and I have never programmed in PHP before so please forgive if the question is very basic. I am trying to accept user input of an image,resize it and display it on my php page. I keep getting the undefined index error and I tried looking at a lot of forums but I just cannot see the difference between codes anymore. So I thought maybe an expert opinion is needed here. I am posting my html and php code here please let me know what Im doing wrong.

```
<html>
<title>Milestone 0</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css"/>
<body>
<div class="head">
   <h1>MILESTONE 0</h1>
</div>
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="navRight"></div>
<div class="content">
   <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Select image to upload:
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
   </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Php file is as follows:

```
<?php

echo "php file";
$target_dir = "public_html/";

$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";

        $filename = $target_file;
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 500);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 500, $width, $height);
        header("Content-type: image/jpg");
        imagejpg($image_p);
        imagedestroy($image_p);
        imagedestroy($image);
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: On which line is the "undefined index error"?

Comment: Run `phpinfo()`  to check if `file_uploads = On` and what are values of `post_max_size`, and `upload_max_file_size`

Comment: You will have also problem with header after echo.

Comment: @teo   The error is on the $target_file = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]); It says undefined index filetoupload..

Comment: @n-dru file_uploads is on and both max sizes are 50MB.

Comment: Please add var_dump($_FILES); at the first line in your upload.php, browse the image, click upload and show us the output.